# Run ipa on device without cable and not with TestFlight?

Tags: ios

Is it possible to distribute `IPA` to device without `TestFlight`, and not via cable? I have a new MacBook Pro with usb-c and an iPhone. Hard to get company set up `TestFlight`. Any idea how to test on device?

Comment: Yes. Export as ad-hoc and enable OTA. All devices the app is going to be installed on need to be registered **before** exporting though. Go to developer.apple.com, member center, devices and add multiple devices using their UDIDs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Ad-Hoc OTA is the way to go.

#### On developer.apple.com:

1. navigate to your account & login
2. click *Certificates, IDs & Profiles* in the side menu on the left
3. on the left, find *Devices* & click `+`
4. register multiple devices by uploading a spreadsheet including the UDIDs and names of the devices
5. follow the steps to finalize the registration process

You might need to wait 24 hours; I found, it sometimes takes really long for the changes to take effect.

#### Inside Xcode:

1. prep: open Xcode settings, accounts, your account and then re-download all the profiles and certificates
2. archive the product
3. open the Organizer window and find the archive you've just created
4. click *Distribute App*
5. choose *Ad-Hoc*
6. make sure to have *include manifest for OTA installation* **enabled**
7. follow the steps
8. finally, click *export* and choose a location to save the files

Upload all the files (icons, .plist & .ipa) to your server. Note that the server needs to be `https`, this *is* mandatory. If your's isn't, upload it to Dropbox or some other cloud service. If you're using Dropbox, make sure to replace `www.dropbox.com` with `dl.dropboxusercontent.com`.

#### Manifest

1. open the `manifest.plist` file and insert all the new urls

   - again, for dropbox: replace `www.dropbox.com` with `dl.dropboxusercontent.com`
2. upload the manifest plist to a secure server.

#### Link:

```
itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/YourURLHere/manifest.plist
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Diawi](http://www.diawi.com) for `Development & In-house Apps Wireless Installations`

It will require the target devices to be registered into the signed provisioning profile that will be distributed with

Answer (score 0):

For me Fabric is an excellent tool. You can check it out [here](https://get.fabric.io). I often distribute ad-hoc builds using this. It simply sends the app install link in an email and you can open the email from your iOS device and install the build right away.

Answer (score 0):

Try [AppByAir](https://www.appbyair.com) mac application for run ipa direct to iPhone