# Export IPA for Testing instead Appstore with (ad-hoc)

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipa

1. i'm create All Devices in (3 iphone + 1 ipad)
   [Developer Apple account](https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/device/)
2. i'm Generate certificate inf [Developer Apple](https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/profile/) and i'm selected all device in this certificate
3. i'm download certificate and Generate in xcode . everything is good now
4. when i'm click in Build sitting => signin =>Provisioning Profile=>
   its show this message :

The UUID of a valid provisioning profile. A missing or invalid profile will cause a build error (deprecated, use [PROVISIONING_PROFILE_SPECIFIER] instead).

5. however i'm exporte IPA with ad-hoc

   and i'm see the code i'm change Myapp.ipa to Myapp.zip for lock the code
   that what i'm se is there the all provisioning profile in the certificate

   ```
   <string>iOS Team Provisioning Profile: com.myApp.name</string>
   <key>ProvisionedDevices</key>
   <array>
       <string>653125008b5277640d4f640ab94241a4</string>
       <string>h5856dd83f2e34952cae17eb849736ef6</string>
       <string>945a65b488deb77903ab9cc335bc2a9b0</string>
       <string>6654f70cc52dab5c371c22b63e200e916</string>
   </array>
   ```
6. when i'm add the ipa to my IPhone or IPad is not installe is give me erore so what is wrong ?

Thnak you for your time to reading all this :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make sure you've followed all these steps, then you should be good to go.
Give it a try and let me know!

#### On developer.apple.com:

1. navigate to your account & login
2. click *Certificates, IDs & Profiles* in the side menu on the left
3. on the left, find *Devices* & click `+`
4. register multiple devices by uploading a spreadsheet including the UDIDs and names of the devices
5. follow the steps to finalize the registration process

You might need to wait 24 hours; I found, it sometimes takes really long for the changes to take effect.

#### Inside Xcode:

1. prep: open Xcode settings, accounts, your account and then re-download all the profiles and certificates
2. archive the product
3. open the Organizer window and find the archive you've just created
4. click *Distribute App*
5. choose *Ad-Hoc*
6. make sure to have *include manifest for OTA installation* **enabled**
7. follow the steps
8. finally, click *export* and choose a location to save the files

Upload all the files (icons, .plist & .ipa) to your server. Note that the server needs to be `https`, this *is* mandatory. If your's isn't, upload it to Dropbox or some other cloud service. If you're using Dropbox, make sure to replace `www.dropbox.com` with `dl.dropboxusercontent.com`.

#### Manifest

1. open the `manifest.plist` file and insert all the new urls

   - again, for dropbox: replace `www.dropbox.com` with `dl.dropboxusercontent.com`
2. upload the manifest plist to a secure server.

#### Link:

```
itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/YourURLHere/manifest.plist
```

---

Taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46241619/3397217).

Answer (score 3):

You should use `automatically manage signing`.

For that you should select your team.

In  `navigator` click on your project name - under targets - you will find signing section.

In that check the checkbox for `automatically manage signing` and select your team. If you have not any team available then you can add it from `Preferences` of your `xcode` -> `Accounts` -> `+` -> add your apple developer id and password.

After selecting team it will automatically create provisioning profile if your developer account includes your bundle id!

Make sure your device is connected with xcode!

Comment: yes i'm use automatically manage signing . i'm generate the iPA .. but i cant drag the ipa into my phone (with xcode directly is working but i need to drag the ipa to my iphone)

Answer (score 3):

When I exporting to ad-hoc, I created a simple WEB with manifest file. This file will generated automatically when you exporting app to AD-HOC. Thanks this web site you can install app from internet.

**Sample code for WEB:**

```
<html>
<a style="font-size:48px;margin-top:150px;margin-left:250px;float:left;color:#22788D;" 
href="itms-services://?action=download-manifest&amp; url=https://yourAppServer/manifest.plist">Install your APP </a>
</html>
```

---

**Sample of Manifest.plist**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>items</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>assets</key>
            <array>
                <dict>
                    <key>kind</key>
                    <string>software-package</string>
                    <key>url</key>
                    <string>https://yourServercom/YourApp.ipa</string>
                </dict>
                <dict>
                    <key>kind</key>
                    <string>display-image</string>
                    <key>url</key>
                    <string>https://yourServercom/Icon.png</string>
                </dict>
                <dict>
                    <key>kind</key>
                    <string>full-size-image</string>
                    <key>url</key>
                    <string>https://yourServercom/iTunesArtwork.png</string>
                </dict>
            </array>
            <key>metadata</key>
            <dict>
                <key>bundle-identifier</key>
                <string>UserAPP.YourApp</string>
                <key>bundle-version</key>
                <string>1.0</string>
                <key>kind</key>
                <string>software</string>
                <key>title</key>
                <string>YourApp</string>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

It works perfectly for me.

**Good luck!**

Comment: Thank you for your help but This is not the problem .