# Can share ipa file to install locally on iphone

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I used flutter for both `Android` and `IOS`. I want to share both applications to the customer for testing purpose. I can export `apk` file by the following command for Android. I am using Android Studio.

`flutter build android --profile`

I can get the apk file. I just share this `apk` to the client. He can install it on his phone without any requirement.

After I run this command in flutter

`flutter build ios --profile`

It showed the error message

```
No valid code signing certificates were found
You can connect to your Apple Developer account by signing in with your Apple ID
in Xcode and create an iOS Development Certificate as well as a Provisioning 
Profile for your project by:
  1- Open the Flutter project's Xcode target with
       open ios/Runner.xcworkspace
  2- Select the 'Runner' project in the navigator then the 'Runner' target
     in the project settings
  3- In the 'General' tab, make sure a 'Development Team' is selected. 
     You may need to:
         - Log in with your Apple ID in Xcode first
         - Ensure you have a valid unique Bundle ID
         - Register your device with your Apple Developer Account
         - Let Xcode automatically provision a profile for your app
  4- Build or run your project again
  5- Trust your newly created Development Certificate on your iOS device
     via Settings > General > Device Management > [your new certificate] > Trus
```

I have no idea how to export to get `ipa` file. I am new to ios development. And also I am not sure that the customer can install this `ipa` file on his iphone without using xcode.

Any idea for exporting customer review applications(ipa, apk) in ios development? And which softwares need for customer?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to install ipa on device over the air, without connecting to Xcode.

You can use services like Crashlytics Beta http://try.crashlytics.com/beta/ or Apple's TestFlight. First one in much easier IMO and does not require a build to be reviewed by Apple review team.

However your build must be signed at least with Ad-Hoc distribution profile and this profile must include target device's unique device identifier UDID.

This answer could be helpful for you https://stackoverflow.com/a/47053605/979822

But before that you should fix everything that was written in your error message.