# How to Building Standalone Apps react native expo for real device?

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native

Good Morning Dear . I'm a young developer of react native .
In my Company has a new one app but I need the build it for ios device .but I'm not yet have the developer account of apple. I just want to the app can be run on real device of ios no need to upload to the app store . How to I can build it ?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for export your app in `xcode` you can get `.ipa` format as `adhoc`, for run this format don't need add app in app store but you need developer account for create `certification` and `provitionProfile` for your app. for more info see that: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47036056/export-ipa-for-testing-instead-appstore-with-ad-hoc)

- some way exist for get build without developer account , but that's maybe cause some problem like , increase application size!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the app can run on a ios device without a developer accounts. You will need a Mac with Xcode installed. You can follow [Expo](https://docs.expo.io/) to start things started.