# Create URL for ipa. Link not working

Tags: ios, ipa

I created three file to download ipa. But The link is not working mean I cant download the application from browser.

```
MyProject.ipa
manifest.plist
a.html
```

manifest.plist

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>items</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>assets</key>
            <array>
                <dict>
                    <key>kind</key>
                    <string>software-package</string>
                    <key>url</key>                        <string>https://www.dropbox.com/s/testUser/MyProject.ipa?dl=0</string> 
                </dict>
            </array>
            <key>metadata</key>
            <dict>
                <key>bundle-identifier</key>
                <string>com.ttt.app</string>
                <key>bundle-version</key>
                <string>1.0.0</string>
                <key>kind</key>
                <string>software</string>
                <key>title</key>
                <string>app</string>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </array>
</dict>
```

a.html

```
<a href="itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=https://www.dropbox.com/s/testUser/manifest.plist?dl=0">Install App</a>
```

Please help to find my issue. Thanks all. :)

Comment: I write here how to create this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47036056/export-ipa-for-testing-instead-appstore-with-ad-hoc/47037090#47037090

Comment: yes totally same. help me find why not ok.

Comment: Check out my answer on this topic here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46241619/3397217

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Dropbox as your `https` server, you *must* replace "dropbox.com" with "dl.dropboxusercontent.com" in **all links**, otherwise it won't work.

See my answer over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46241619/3397217).