# i need to share my iPA file to the tester without using testflight or fabric

Tags: ios

we have an custom app (ex:Restaurant app) based on merchant requirement we will modify that app based on AppID's, differentiating all the apps. To get IPA for every app we need to upload it to test flight or fabric
Is there any alternative to generate an IPA(we have seen that android apps have this facility to generate an apk, so is there any possibility to generate IPA for IOS(instead of manually changing the Appid, Imageicon, Splashes, Appname)by keeping the app in server)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46241255/9136962

Answer (score 0):

You first need to generate an Adhoc build, for that device id of tester's iOS device should be inserted in your developer account.

You can use https://www.diawi.com/ to upload your adhoc build and can share the URL with the testers.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [AppByAir](https://appbyair.com/) Mac application for sharing build on Wireless Installations

You simply follow 2 steps to get URL that you share with tester or client.
(need that devices register with developer account.)

1. Select or drage and Drop your ipa file.
2. Click on upload to get the installation link.